# why is scanf not pointing to the proper number?

Tags: c, scanf

i'm attempting to have scanf receive input from a user in the form of a number then use the two numbers i ask for to  preform some simple math the problem I'm having is that no matter what i enter for the numbers they always just spit out 1 any help would be appreciated

## include

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
float in1,in2,value;
char c;

printf("Enter the operation of your choice:\n");
printf("A. add           S. subtract\n");
printf("M. multiply      D. divide\n");
printf("Q. quit\n");
c=getchar();

while( c !='Q' && c!='q')
{
    printf("please enter your first number:");
    scanf("%g", &in1);
    printf("%g\n",in1 );

    printf("please enter your second number:");
    scanf("%g", &in2);
    printf("%g\n",in2 );

    if(c == 'S' || c =='s')
        if(in2 == 0)
        {
            printf("you have selected subtration however\n");
            printf("the value you entered was 0\n");
            printf("please enter a value greater than 0\n");
            scanf("%lg",&in2);
        }

    if(c == 'a' || c == 'A')
    {
        value = in1+in2;
        printf("%lg + %lg = %lg\n",in1,in2,value );
    }

    if(c == 's' || c == 'S')
    {
        value = in1-in2;
        printf("%lg - %lg = %lg\n",in1,in2,value );
    }   

    if(c == 'm' || c == 'M')
    {
        value = in1*in2;
        printf("%lg * %lg = %lg\n",in1,in2,value );
    }   

    if(c == 'd' || c == 'D')
    {
        value = in1/in2;
        printf("%lg / %lg = %lg\n",in1,in2,value );
    }   
    if (c !='Q' && c !='q')
    {
        printf("Enter the operation of your choice:\n");
        printf("A. add           S. subtract\n");
        printf("M. multiply      D. divide\n");
        printf("Q. quit\n");    
    }
    c=getchar();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact content of the console when you run this program ?

Comment: _Always_ check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: sure when run the console spits out
"please enter your first number:"
"1.000000"
"please enter your second number:"
"1.000000"

Comment: The program fragment as shown doesn't compile cleanly for me.  It complains about in2 not being a double.  When I fix this, it works fine......

Comment: for `scanf`, `%lg` requires a `double*` argument, not a `float*`. Use `%g` (or `%f`) instead.

Comment: i will post my complete program shortly then

Comment: side note i am a student any advice(formatting, shortcuts, ect.) will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please define your variables to be `double` instead of `float`? Also, I feel you require one more `getchar()` at the end of while loop. When you enter the 2nd number first time, the enter key is taken as part of `c = getchar()`; To read the option once more, you will have to include another `c = getchar()`.

Comment: hmmm interesting i changed it and no such luck i can post the rest of my code but i dont think the rest of my code is the problem seeing as how the printf statements right after the scanf statements are not returning the right value

Comment: hmm.. I tried this piece of code and I can observe that my output follows the input. Which environment are you working on?

Comment: Can you please try with `double in1,in2,value;`

Comment: that worked which is weird because it didn't work about a half hour ago when i first tried that. lol i'm a little more than confused but thank you for your help i'm assuming when i tried before i had an improperly formatted